# Boost condition deadlock using wait() in producer-consumer code

Tags: c++, boost, conditional-statements, wait, producer-consumer

I have implemented a basic threaded producer-consumer (thread 1 = producer, thread 2 = consumer) using Boost threads and conditions. I am getting stuck in **wait()** indefinitely quite often. I can't really see what could be wrong here. Below is some pseudo-code:

```
// main class
class Main {
public:
  void AddToQueue(...someData...)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    m_queue.push_back(new QueueItem(...someData...));
    m_cond.notify_one(); 
  }

  void RemoveQueuedItem(...someCond...)
  {
    // i'm wondering if this could cause the trouble?
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    // erase a item matching condition (some code not shown,
    // but should be fairly self-explanatory -- IsMatch()
    // simply looks at a flag of QueueItem
    m_queue.erase(std::remove_if(m_queue.being(), m_queue.end(),
      boost::bind(&Main::IsMatch, this, _1, someCond), m_queue.end());
  }

  friend void WorkerThread(Main* m);
private:      
  boost::ptr_deque<QueueItem> m_queue;
  boost::mutex m_mutex;
  boost::condition m_cond;
};

// worker thread
void WorkerThread(Main* m)
{
  typedef boost::ptr_deque<QueueItem>::auto_type RelType;
  RelType queueItem;

  while(!shutDown) {
    { // begin mutex scope
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m->m_mutex);
      while(m->m_queue.empty()) {
        m->m_cond.wait(lock); // <- stuck here forever quite often!
      }
      queueItem = m->m_queue->pop_front(); // pop & take ptr ownership
    } // end mutex scope

    // ... do stuff with queueItem
    // ...
    // ... queueItem is deleted when it leaves scope & we loop around
  }
}
```

Some additional information:

- Using Boost v1.44
- Issue is occurring in Linux and Android; I'm not yet sure if it happens in Windows

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
I *believe* I have isolated the issue. I'll update further once confirmed, which hopefully will be tomorrow.

**UPDATE 2**:
It turns out there is no issue in the code described above. I was reliant on a underlying API for AddToQueue() - when processing data in the worker thread & handing it back to the API, it had a circular bug where it would call AddToQueue() again... which is now fixed ;-)

Comment: Your code above lacks the part where you wait on the on the conditional variable. Paste it too.

Comment: In my worker thread (consumer) above, you'll see a while(queue_is_empty()) { cond.wait(lock); } Is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar recently even though mine uses the STL queue. See if you can pick out from my implementation. As [wilx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341065/wilx) says, you need to wait on the condition. My implementation has maximum limit on the elements in the queue and I use that to wait for the mutex/guard to be freed.

I originally did this on Windows with ability to use Mutex or Critical sections in mind hence the template parameter which you can remove and use `boost::mutex` directly if it simplifies it for you.

```
#include <queue>
#include "Message.h"
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>

template <typename T> class Queue :  private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
  // constructor binds the condition object to the Q mutex
  Queue(T & mutex, size_t max_size) :  m_max_size(max_size), m_mutex(mutex){}

  // writes messages to end of Q 
  void put(const Message & msg)
  {
    // Lock mutex to ensure exclusive access to Q
    boost::unique_lock<T> guard(m_mutex);

    // while Q is full, sleep waiting until something is taken off of it
    while (m_queue.size() == m_max_size)
    {
      cond.wait(guard);
    }

    // ok, room on the queue. 
    // Add the message to the queue
    m_queue.push(msg);

    // Indicate so data can be ready from Q
    cond.notify_one();
  }

  // Read message from front of Q. Message is removed from the Q
  Message get(void)
  {
    // Lock mutex to ensure exclusive access to Q
    boost::unique_lock<T> guard(m_mutex);

    // If Q is empty, sleep waiting for something to be put onto it
    while (m_queue.empty())
    {
      cond.wait(guard);
    }

    // Q not empty anymore, read the value
    Message msg = m_queue.front();

    // Remove it from the queue
    m_queue.pop();

    // Signal so more data can be added to Q
    cond.notify_one();

    return msg;
  }

  size_t max_size(void) const
  {
    return m_max_size;
  }


private:
  const size_t m_max_size;
  T & m_mutex;
  std::queue<Message> m_queue;
  boost::condition_variable_any cond;
};
```

This way, you can share the queue across the producer/consumer. Example usage

```
boost::mutex mutex;

Queue<boost::mutex> q(mutex, 100);

boost::thread_group threads;

threads.create_thread(Producer<boost::mutex>(q));
threads.create_thread(Consumer<boost::mutex>(q));

threads.join_all();
```

With Producer/Consumer defined as below

```
template <typename T> class Producer
{
public:
   // Queue passed in
   explicit Producer(Queue<T> &q) :  m_queue(q) {}

   void operator()()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't have a bug in the producer-consumer portion of my code (will post details in main post in a bit). I really like your implementation though, think I might re factor some of mine to something similar.

Comment: Cheers. Glad to make a contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
m->m_cond.wait(); // <- stuck here forever quite often!
```

should be:

```
m->m_cond.wait( lock );
```

You dead locked your classs because you had still the mutex accquired but you were waiting. Every other method wants to accquire the same mutex and wait for your worker which will never release the mutex.

Comment: Sorry, that is just a typo in my pseudo code. I have corrected it above. Actual code has been implemented waiting on actual lock (boost::mutex::scoped_lock<>).

Comment: Ok then out of curiousity please post the code for adding something to the queue.

Comment: It's already there as Queue(). I have since renamed the function in the pseudo code above to AddToQueue() for clarity.